# Basic JavaScript Question - Conversion from CM to Feet

Tags: javascript

[Image Number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu7WG.png)

I'm currently doing some practice and I'm getting that I'm not passing. I've tried writing it out like this also,

```
function feet(){
let cm = 100

return cm / 30.48}
```

Please see link with image above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Function looks okay, you have to call it to run.

Comment: The exercize suggests that the input should be an argument, not a constant.

Comment: It should executes well

Answer (score 1):

As written in your question, you need to take parameter of cm(centimeter).

```
    function cmToFeet(cm){
    
       return cm / 30.48;
    }
    
    
    let returnValue = cmToFeet(100);
    console.log(returnValue);
```

Comment: @RandoMWoN if this answer is what you were looking for, can you mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine. What is the error that you are getting. Probably are you not calling the function after declaring it.

```
    function feet() {
      let cm = 100
      return cm * 0.0328084
    }
    feet();
```